# How to use only tab (not space) in vim

Tags: vim, indentation

I prefer to use `tab` than `white space`(may be a little different from most of others)

But I found, when I hit `Enter` at the end of line, it will add some **white spaces**, but not **tab**. So, I have to delete them and press **tab**.

I want to know how to set vim as:

1. use only **tab** to indent the lines
2. a tab looks like 4-spaces, but actually is a tab
3. when hit `enter` at the end of a line, the new line is started with only tabs

I've googled for this for a while, but not found a good answer. Thank you in advance

---

**UPDATE**

The answer @Alok has provided works well in most of cases. But I just found, sometimes, it depends on the file type. For example, if you are editing a `haml` file, and there is a `haml.vim` in your `vimfiles/indent/`, then all the tabs will be converted to `space`. So if you want it to be `tab` only, you should modify(or delete) the corresponding indent file.

Comment: Instead of modifying installed files, try putting your overriding settings in `$HOME/vimfiles/after/indent/haml.vim`.  See `:help after-directory` for more info.

Comment: It is common to have different tab/space preferences for different filetypes. Check out my screencast over at Vimcasts.org, which shows how to [set whitespace preferences for different file types](http://vimcasts.org/episodes/whitespace-preferences-and-filetypes/). This solution uses your vimrc, but if you want to set up lots of different filetypes, you might prefer to use the after-directory, as suggested by Nefrubyr.

Comment: The /after/indent trick also works to get rid of those pesky spaces in python files, the offending file to look at is ftplugin/python.vim, just copy the line with setlocal and copy it to a blank file as suggested by @Nefrubyr, edit it and restore sanity.

Answer (score 170, accepted):

The settings you are looking for are:

```
set autoindent
set noexpandtab
set tabstop=4
set shiftwidth=4
```

As single line:

```
set autoindent noexpandtab tabstop=4 shiftwidth=4
```

`autoindent` can be replaced with `smartindent` or `cindent`, depending upon your tastes.  Also look at `filetype plugin indent on`.

http://vim.wikia.com/wiki/Indenting_source_code

Comment: As @freewind said, it does no work well when working with `.haml` files. In my case I use **vim janus** and I just add the suggested single line but it does not work for `haml` files. Any idea?

Comment: Add `softtabstop=-1`, too.

Comment: If you are using neovim have a look on `:help option` because at least "autoindent and noexpandtab" are default options.

Comment: Is there some quick way for alternating back and forth between using tabs or spaces? Should I open a new SO quest?

Answer (score 15):

Late to the discussion, just for anyone who struggled to force the use of tabs. With the current version of *vim* (*>8*) it was required to set:

```
:set noet ci pi sts=0 sw=4 ts=4
```

which expands to:

```
:set noexpandtab
:set copyindent
:set preserveindent
:set softtabstop=0
:set shiftwidth=4
:set tabstop=4
```

We can also use this setup with only specific file types, taking advantage of `setlocal`:

```
autocmd FileType c,cpp,java,python setlocal noet ci pi sts=0 sw=4 ts=4
```

For further reference, see: https://vim.fandom.com/wiki/Indent_with_tabs,_align_with_spaces

Comment: You can `alias vimt="vim +'set noet ci pi sts=0 sw=4 ts=4'"` if you don't use tabs, but have to work on a project that used tabs, so that you stay coherent with the project's guidelines when you change some code.

Answer (score 1):

In my case `set indentexpr=` did the trick.

I have found the config files which set the annoying behavior with `fd python.vim  /`. In `/usr/share/vim/vim90/indent/python.vim` there is the line `setlocal indentexpr=python#GetIndent(v:lnum)`. The function `python#GetIndent` is defined in `/usr/share/vim/vim90/autoload/python.vim`. This function returned a weird value which was not a multiple of `shiftwidth` and `tabstop`. Therefore vim inserted a tab followed by some spaces.

Now, that I have set `indentexpr` to an empty value, I think vim falls back to `autoindent`. `smartindent` and `cindent` are turned off. (https://vimhelp.org/indent.txt.html)

Of course `set noexpandtab` is required, too. I am not sure if any other settings are relevant here.

---

EDIT: `autoindent` is not perfect, it does nothing more than indent the new line as much as the previous line.

```
set smartindent
set cinwords=if,elif,else,try,except,finally,with,for,while,class,def
```

does not work as expected and `cindent` does not seem suitable for python, so using `indentexpr` is the way to go after all.

Luckily the indentation function can be configured, see `help ft-python-indent` or look at the code – that was more informative regarding the disable_parentheses_indenting feature. It seems this is the solution for me:

```
if !exists('g:python_indent')
    let g:python_indent = {}
endif
let g:python_indent.disable_parentheses_indenting = 1
```

(https://vi.stackexchange.com/a/38824/43863)