# Vim-go - Indent with tabs not whitespaces

Tags: vim, go

I'd like to have my go files indented with tabs not whitespaces. 
When I run `:set expandtab` then `:retab` I get what I want but it automatically switches back to an indentation with whitespaces everytime I save the file.

I am using the `vim-go` plugin but I couldn't find anything in the doc/code which could lead to this issue. I have tried changing to `setlocal noexpandtab` in ftplugin/go.vim but it didn't work

How can I change this?

Many thanks

Answer (score 0):

Put that in the `~/.vimrc` file to make the settings permanent.
Here's a wiki article on this - http://vim.wikia.com/wiki/Indent_with_tabs,_align_with_spaces

Comment: It's already in my vimrc but somehow it seems to have been overwritten somewhere else

Comment: May be you are missing something. Check out this answer out - http://stackoverflow.com/a/3682602

Comment: This solution won't work because vim-go runs your code through `gofmt`, which by default uses tabs to indent. So your vim settings won't be any help here. You can however, disable auto format on save by putting this on your vim config: `let g:go_fmt_autosave=0` and `let g:go_asmfmt_autosave=0`