# How to make vim not indent with leading spaces?

Tags: vim, indentation

I'd like vim to indent with only tabs, but using `=` keeps giving me a leading 2 spaces after a series of tabs.

I have attempted many methods, including everything here [How to use only tab (not space) in vim](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3682582/how-to-use-only-tab-not-space-in-vim). I have `autoindent noexpandtab tabstop=8 shiftwidth=8 copyindent preserveindent softtabstop=0`, but applying `=` in vim still gives me leading spaces of 2. I have tried looking at loaded filetype plugins and have not been able to debug the issue.

Why might this be happening, and how can I fix it?

(Edit: I'm noticing that this occurs even with `vim -u NONE`)

(Edit: supplementary information)

My `indentexpr` and `equalprg` are both set to nothing. Primarily, I'm editing Javascript files, and with `debug` and `breakadd file *.vim`, I'm able to see that vim loads `.../share/vim/vim90/syntax/javascript.vim` with the following contents:

```
" Vim syntax file
" Language: JavaScript
" Maintainer:   Claudio Fleiner <claudio@fleiner.com>
" Updaters: Scott Shattuck (ss) <ss@technicalpursuit.com>
" URL:      http://www.fleiner.com/vim/syntax/javascript.vim
" Changes:  (ss) added keywords, reserved words, and other identifiers
"       (ss) repaired several quoting and grouping glitches
"       (ss) fixed regex parsing issue with multiple qualifiers [gi]
"       (ss) additional factoring of keywords, globals, and members
" Last Change:  2022 Jun 09
"       2013 Jun 12: adjusted javaScriptRegexpString (Kevin Locke)
"       2018 Apr 14: adjusted javaScriptRegexpString (LongJohnCoder)

" tuning parameters:
" unlet javaScript_fold

if !exists("main_syntax")
  " quit when a syntax file was already loaded
  if exists("b:current_syntax")
    finish
  endif
  let main_syntax = 'javascript'
elseif exists("b:current_syntax") && b:current_syntax == "javascript"
  finish
endif

let s:cpo_save = &cpo
set cpo&vim


syn keyword javaScriptCommentTodo      TODO FIXME XXX TBD contained
syn match   javaScriptLineComment      "\/\/.*" contains=@Spell,javaScriptCommentTodo
syn match   javaScriptCommentSkip      "^[ \t]*\*\($\|[ \t]\+\)"
syn region  javaScriptComment          start="/\*"  end="\*/" contains=@Spell,javaScriptCommentTodo
syn match   javaScriptSpecial          "\\\d\d\d\|\\."
syn region  javaScriptStringD          start=+"+  skip=+\\\\\|\\"+  end=+"\|$+  contains=javaScriptSpecial,@htmlPreproc
syn region  javaScriptStringS          start=+'+  skip=+\\\\\|\\'+  end=+'\|$+  contains=javaScriptSpecial,@htmlPreproc
syn region  javaScriptStringT          start=+`+  skip=+\\\\\|\\`+  end=+`+ contains=javaScriptSpecial,javaScriptEmbed,@htmlPreproc

syn region  javaScriptEmbed        start=+${+  end=+}+  contains=@javaScriptEmbededExpr

" number handling by Christopher Leonard chris.j.leonard@gmx.com
syn match   javaScriptSpecialCharacter "'\\.'"
syn match   javaScriptNumber           "\<0[bB][0-1]\+\(_[0-1]\+\)*\>"
syn match   javaScriptNumber           "\<0[oO][0-7]\+\(_[0-7]\+\)*\>"
syn match   javaScriptNumber           "\<0\([0-7]\+\(_[0-7]\+\)*\)\?\>"
syn match   javaScriptNumber           "\<0[xX][0-9a-fA-F]\+\(_[0-9a-fA-F]\+\)*\>"
syn match   javaScriptNumber           "\<\d\+\(_\d\+\)*[eE][+-]\?\d\+\>"
syn match   javaScriptNumber           "\<[1-9]\d*\(_\d\+\)*\(\.\(\d\+\(_\d\+\)*\([eE][+-]\?\d\+\)\?\)\?\)\?\>"
syn match   javaScriptNumber           "\<\(\d\+\(_\d\+\)*\)\?\.\d\+\(_\d\+\)*\([eE][+-]\?\d\+\)\?\>"
syn match   javaScriptNumber           "\<\d\+\(_\d\+\)*\.\(\d\+\(_\d\+\)*\([eE][+-]\?\d\+\)\?\)\?\>"
syn region  javaScriptRegexpString     start=+[,(=+]\s*/[^/*]+ms=e-1,me=e-1 skip=+\\\\\|\\/+ end=+/[gimuys]\{0,2\}\s*$+ end=+/[gimuys]\{0,2\}\s*[+;.,)\]}]+me=e-1 end=+/[gimuys]\{0,2\}\s\+\/+me=e-1 contains=@htmlPreproc,javaScriptComment oneline

syn keyword javaScriptConditional   if else switch
syn keyword javaScriptRepeat        while for do in
syn keyword javaScriptBranch        break continue
syn keyword javaScriptOperator      new delete instanceof typeof
syn keyword javaScriptType      Array Boolean Date Function Number Object String RegExp
syn keyword javaScriptStatement     return with await
syn keyword javaScriptBoolean       true false
syn keyword javaScriptNull      null undefined
syn keyword javaScriptIdentifier    arguments this var let
syn keyword javaScriptLabel     case default
syn keyword javaScriptException     try catch finally throw
syn keyword javaScriptMessage       alert confirm prompt status
syn keyword javaScriptGlobal        self window top parent
syn keyword javaScriptMember        document event location 
syn keyword javaScriptDeprecated    escape unescape
syn keyword javaScriptReserved      abstract boolean byte char class const debugger double enum export extends final float goto implements import int interface long native package private protected public short static super synchronized throws transient volatile async

syn cluster  javaScriptEmbededExpr  contains=javaScriptBoolean,javaScriptNull,javaScriptIdentifier,javaScriptStringD,javaScriptStringS,javaScriptStringT

if exists("javaScript_fold")
    syn match   javaScriptFunction  "\<function\>"
    syn region  javaScriptFunctionFold  start="\<function\>.*[^};]$" end="^\z1}.*$" transparent fold keepend

    syn sync match javaScriptSync   grouphere javaScriptFunctionFold "\<function\>"
    syn sync match javaScriptSync   grouphere NONE "^}"

    setlocal foldmethod=syntax
    setlocal foldtext=getline(v:foldstart)
else
    syn keyword javaScriptFunction  function
    syn match   javaScriptBraces       "[{}\[\]]"
    syn match   javaScriptParens       "[()]"
endif

if main_syntax == "javascript"
  syn sync fromstart
  syn sync maxlines=100

  syn sync ccomment javaScriptComment
endif

" Define the default highlighting.
" Only when an item doesn't have highlighting yet
hi def link javaScriptComment       Comment
hi def link javaScriptLineComment       Comment
hi def link javaScriptCommentTodo       Todo
hi def link javaScriptSpecial       Special
hi def link javaScriptStringS       String
hi def link javaScriptStringD       String
hi def link javaScriptStringT       String
hi def link javaScriptCharacter     Character
hi def link javaScriptSpecialCharacter  javaScriptSpecial
hi def link javaScriptNumber        javaScriptValue
hi def link javaScriptConditional       Conditional
hi def link javaScriptRepeat        Repeat
hi def link javaScriptBranch        Conditional
hi def link javaScriptOperator      Operator
hi def link javaScriptType          Type
hi def link javaScriptStatement     Statement
hi def link javaScriptFunction      Function
hi def link javaScriptBraces        Function
hi def link javaScriptError     Error
hi def link javaScrParenError       javaScriptError
hi def link javaScriptNull          Keyword
hi def link javaScriptBoolean       Boolean
hi def link javaScriptRegexpString      String

hi def link javaScriptIdentifier        Identifier
hi def link javaScriptLabel     Label
hi def link javaScriptException     Exception
hi def link javaScriptMessage       Keyword
hi def link javaScriptGlobal        Keyword
hi def link javaScriptMember        Keyword
hi def link javaScriptDeprecated        Exception 
hi def link javaScriptReserved      Keyword
hi def link javaScriptDebug     Debug
hi def link javaScriptConstant      Label
hi def link javaScriptEmbed     Special



let b:current_syntax = "javascript"
if main_syntax == 'javascript'
  unlet main_syntax
endif
let &cpo = s:cpo_save
unlet s:cpo_save

" vim: ts=8
```

Checking `:scriptnames` yields the following loaded files

```
  1: /nix/store/znpi2hc0ijkmd3ckv8pw3m7jcmyms3iz-vimrc
  2: /nix/store/ps4mgh61nkbq4clrfvpc1rdgsgf5jid9-vim-full-9.0.1441/share/vim/vim90/syntax/syntax.vim
  3: /nix/store/ps4mgh61nkbq4clrfvpc1rdgsgf5jid9-vim-full-9.0.1441/share/vim/vim90/syntax/synload.vim
  4: /nix/store/ps4mgh61nkbq4clrfvpc1rdgsgf5jid9-vim-full-9.0.1441/share/vim/vim90/syntax/syncolor.vim
  5: /nix/store/ps4mgh61nkbq4clrfvpc1rdgsgf5jid9-vim-full-9.0.1441/share/vim/vim90/colors/lists/default.vim
  6: /nix/store/ps4mgh61nkbq4clrfvpc1rdgsgf5jid9-vim-full-9.0.1441/share/vim/vim90/filetype.vim
  7: /nix/store/ps4mgh61nkbq4clrfvpc1rdgsgf5jid9-vim-full-9.0.1441/share/vim/vim90/scripts.vim
  8: /nix/store/ps4mgh61nkbq4clrfvpc1rdgsgf5jid9-vim-full-9.0.1441/share/vim/vim90/autoload/dist/script.vim
  9: /nix/store/ps4mgh61nkbq4clrfvpc1rdgsgf5jid9-vim-full-9.0.1441/share/vim/vim90/colors/quiet.vim
 10: /nix/store/ps4mgh61nkbq4clrfvpc1rdgsgf5jid9-vim-full-9.0.1441/share/vim/vim90/plugin/getscriptPlugin.vim
 11: /nix/store/ps4mgh61nkbq4clrfvpc1rdgsgf5jid9-vim-full-9.0.1441/share/vim/vim90/plugin/gzip.vim
 12: /nix/store/ps4mgh61nkbq4clrfvpc1rdgsgf5jid9-vim-full-9.0.1441/share/vim/vim90/plugin/logiPat.vim
 13: /nix/store/ps4mgh61nkbq4clrfvpc1rdgsgf5jid9-vim-full-9.0.1441/share/vim/vim90/plugin/manpager.vim
 14: /nix/store/ps4mgh61nkbq4clrfvpc1rdgsgf5jid9-vim-full-9.0.1441/share/vim/vim90/plugin/matchparen.vim
 15: /nix/store/ps4mgh61nkbq4clrfvpc1rdgsgf5jid9-vim-full-9.0.1441/share/vim/vim90/plugin/netrwPlugin.vim
 16: /nix/store/ps4mgh61nkbq4clrfvpc1rdgsgf5jid9-vim-full-9.0.1441/share/vim/vim90/plugin/rrhelper.vim
 17: /nix/store/ps4mgh61nkbq4clrfvpc1rdgsgf5jid9-vim-full-9.0.1441/share/vim/vim90/plugin/spellfile.vim
 18: /nix/store/ps4mgh61nkbq4clrfvpc1rdgsgf5jid9-vim-full-9.0.1441/share/vim/vim90/plugin/tarPlugin.vim
 19: /nix/store/ps4mgh61nkbq4clrfvpc1rdgsgf5jid9-vim-full-9.0.1441/share/vim/vim90/plugin/tohtml.vim
 20: /nix/store/ps4mgh61nkbq4clrfvpc1rdgsgf5jid9-vim-full-9.0.1441/share/vim/vim90/plugin/vimballPlugin.vim
 21: /nix/store/ps4mgh61nkbq4clrfvpc1rdgsgf5jid9-vim-full-9.0.1441/share/vim/vim90/plugin/zipPlugin.vim
 22: /nix/store/yg583igd7jckx9s0kxw4gwhzxh1lnxq4-vimplugin-vim-sensible-2023-03-29/plugin/sensible.vim
```

Comment: Welcome to SO. Reading `:help =` will point you to the options `equalprg` and `indentexpr`. What are these set to? You are already looking at filetype plugins. With which filetypes do you experience issues? Please [edit] and tell us.

Comment: I had gone through the `:help =` page but to no avail. These are both set to nothing. The problem baffles me. (Edit: let me add this in the question)

Comment: [vi.se] may help.

Comment: File `syntax/javascript.vim` is a *syntax* file and has nothing to do with indentation. You're looking for `indent/javascript.vim`. Those files come with Vim, you need not share them in your question. Open a Javascript file and repeat your inspection of options.

Comment: @Friedrich I realised that even`vim -u NONE` produces the same behavior, so I suppose none of those files are the issue?

Comment: Agreed, the indent functions are tab/space agnostic. I realized late. Could you provide a sample file where this happens?

Comment: @Friedrich I think I figured out part of the issue. Even though I had `nocindent` set, and all my indent settings like `indentexpr` were empty, my symptoms were probably as if cindent was being applied. My leading spaces would come in cases including whenever I continued a line with unclosed parenthesis, or had new lines with leading commas. Although I'm still not exactly sure which part of cindent would give me my leading spaces, after reading the manual https://vimhelp.org/indent.txt.html#cinoptions-values (to be continued)

Comment: , with experimentation, I found that setting anything to `indextexpr` would no longer manifest the behavior, so now I've resorted to `set indentexpr=(cindent(v:lnum)/8)*8` to force whatever cindent was happening to align on tabs.

Comment: Glad you found a solution. Instead of comments, please post an answer below so other users can learn from your issue. SO encourages self-answers. You should be able to accept it after 48 hours.

Answer (score 0):

(Reposted from comments)

I think I figured out part of the issue.

Even though I had `nocindent` set, and all my indent settings like `indentexpr` were empty, my symptoms were probably as if `cindent` was being applied. My leading spaces would come in cases including whenever I continued a line with unclosed parenthesis, or had new lines with leading commas.

Although I'm still not exactly sure which part of cindent would give me my leading spaces after reading the manual https://vimhelp.org/indent.txt.html#cinoptions-values, with experimentation, I found that setting anything to `indextexpr` would no longer manifest the behavior.

Now I've resorted to `set indentexpr=(cindent(v:lnum)/8)*8` to force whatever `cindent` was happening to align on tabs.